# Out of Memory Error in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, out-of-memory

Good afternoon,

Receiving the out of memory error in my code, any suggestions to change to code?

Inputs from column A are transferred to 2 different cells.

Output 1: Concatenates all the data from column A with commas inserted - between each cell value
Output 2: Concatenates all the data from column A with commas and quotes inserted - for every cell value

Thanks

```
Sub Inserting_Commas()
' Macro to insert commas at the end of end cell value & to convert values from rows to single column

Range("A2").Select

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim outputStr As String
Dim outputStr2 As String
Dim rownumber As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Seperate the column A by Commas
outputStr = Range("A2")

For rownumber = 3 To lastRow
    outputStr = outputStr & "," & Range("A" & rownumber)
Next

Range("D2") = outputStr

' Seperate the Column with Quotes and Commas
Range("A2").Select

For rownumber = 2 To lastRow
    Range("B" & rownumber).Value = "''" & Range("A" & rownumber) & "'"
Next

' --------------------------------------

outputStr2 = "'" & Range("B2")

For rownumber = 3 To lastRow
    outputStr2 = outputStr2 & "," & Range("B" & rownumber)
Next

Range("D20") = outputStr2

End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to rethink this.  [An Excel cell can only store 32,767 characters.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f)  If you're running out of memory building 2 strings, there's absolutely no way they're going to fit into 2 cells. What is the end goal of your code?

Answer (score 1):

As Comintern has stated, a cell can only hold just under 33,000 characters, when your concatenation tried to place more than this into a cell you will get the error.

The below code does a similar thing to what you had written (although there were some odd single quotes that didn't look right to me so I have removed them) but in less lines of code, it also outputs to a cell whenever the resultant output is over 31000 so as to not exceed the cell size limit.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet
Dim Cl              As Range
Dim StrOutput       As String
Dim StrOutput2      As String
Dim LngRow          As Long

Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LngRow = 2
    For Each Cl In WkSht.Range("A2:A" & WkSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        StrOutput = StrOutput & IIf(StrOutput = "", "", ",") & Cl
        StrOutput2 = StrOutput2 & IIf(StrOutput2 = "", "", ",") & "'" & Cl & "'"

        If Len(StrOutput) > 31000 Then
            WkSht.Range("D" & LngRow) = StrOutput
            WkSht.Range("E" & LngRow) = StrOutput2
            StrOutput = ""
            StrOutput2 = ""
            LngRow = LngRow + 1
        End If

        DoEvents
    Next
Set WkSht = Nothing

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

You could then run each of these output cells in your SQL query but I suspect you could benefit from looking at the whole process. That will be a very text heavy query and you may not be able to run it at all depending on the method used. They would be different questions though *if* they arise at all.

Comment: A cell can hold more than 33 characters.

Comment: Yeah someone else pointed out that typo too, I can't change it till I'm at a computer in about an hour

Comment: @GaryEvans - Got it.  Hope that was what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment under [@George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792262/4088852) that...

> this code is only a partial step. I am using the output data and
>   extract information from a Dashboard (internal system similar to SQL).
>   The dashboard works similar to search engines. If I copy and paste the
>   output cell into dashboard - I can segregate the required dataset.

...there is no reason to try to store the complete output in a cell inside Excel.  An Excel cell can only store [32,767 characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f), so your output is going to be truncated regardless of whether building the string runs out of memory or not.

Since you don't appear to *need* the result inside of Excel, just write it to a text file:

```
Sub Inserting_Commas()
    Dim fso As Object, outFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Foo\bar.txt", True) 'Replace with your own path.

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lastRow As Long, rownumber As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rownumber = 2 To lastRow
            outFile.Write "'" & .Cells(rownumber, 1).Value & "'"
            If rownumber <> lastRow Then outFile.Write ","
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all, I shall definitely explore that option of transferring the data into a text file

Answer (score 0):

How many rows has your list?

The culprit is maybe that part:

```
For rownumber = 3 To lastRow
    outputStr = outputStr & "," & Range("A" & rownumber)
Next
```

Here you are concatenating the string and making it bigger and bigger.

If you have a lot of rows, then you will run out of memory.

Comment: It does work for a 100+ rows, However I have a large set of data possibly 10000+. I have to use this data in SQL to extract data from a different system. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @bik_sas - Are you creating an SQL text file, using ADO, or something else? It still isn't clear why you're trying to write the string you're building to a cell.

Comment: Hi all, this code is only a partial step. I am using the output data and extract information from a Dashboard (internal system similar to SQL). The dashboard works similar to search engines. If I copy and paste the output cell into dashboard - I can segregate the required dataset.